# Is there a way to see which IPs are sending data to Google Analytics? Need to check if all instances of application are sending data

Tags: google-analytics

I guess the title explains itself, but anyway... I have a **PHP web application** running on three different instances of Ubuntu, they are all **AWS EC2 instances** behind a load balancer.

The thing is, **recently the team needed to change a lot of the code and had to redeploy the whole project from scratch on 2 of the 3 VMs** and at the same our **users access metrics on Google Analytics dropped significantly**. I don't know if these are related (the drop in user/min and the code rework).

So I was trying to make sure that Google is receiving data as it should, but I **can't find a way on Google Analytics to see if the data shown there is being sent by 3 different machines**, or even see what are the IPs that are sending the data so I can be sure that the 3 scripts are running like intended.

Is there a way on Google Analytics to see the where the data is coming from? Is it something I need to activate? Create a new metric/property or whatever? Am I just missing where this data is accessible?

Thanks in advance for any input.